# I can't see my CSS properties on my website while working NODE.JS and Liveserver

Tags: css, node.js, liveserver

I am new at Node.js so i have problem and I couldn't figure it out. Problem is I can't see my css properties in my website when I try to send my index.html with node.js. I will share with my directory and also codes so may you can find what is wrong. I should tell that when I try to click right on my html then hit the click on open with live server I can see my CSS properly but when I try to call with node.js I can't see them.

HTTP Status for CSS file is 200 so everything is fine there but I still can't see my css

```
// I send my index.html as a Homepage here

app.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./','views','index.html'));
});


//Here my <link tag in index.html 

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/dist/css/style.css"/>
```

[And you can see my directory here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfkIv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the `dist/` directory public so that browser can read files from them.

Try adding this line

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));
```

Recommended to put this before your routes start.